# How to get the label in the result of an array

Tags: php, arrays, label

The following code works as expected to get the number of patients per age group.

It also gets the highest (or most common) age group.

```
$count_0_19 = 0;
$count_20_29 = 0;
$count_30_39 = 0;
$count_40_49 = 0;
$count_50_59 = 0;
$count_above_60 = 0;
$curr_year = date('Y');

$sql= "SELECT pt_dob FROM ptlist WHERE mid=$userID";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

$pt_dob = $row[ 'pt_dob' ];

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$pt_dob = explode('-', $row['pt_dob']);
$year = $pt_dob[0];
$month = $pt_dob[1];
$day = $pt_dob
$temp = abs($curr_year - $year);

if($temp >= 0 && $temp <= 19) {
$count_0_19++;
  }
elseif($temp >= 20 && $temp <= 29) {
$count_20_29++;
  }
elseif($temp >= 30 && $temp <= 39) {
$count_30_39++;
  }
elseif($temp >= 40 && $temp <= 49) {
$count_40_49++;
  }
elseif($temp >= 50 && $temp <= 59) {
$count_50_59++;
  }
else {
$count_above_60++;
  }
}

echo '0-19: '.$count_0_19.'<br>';
echo '20-29: '.$count_20_29.'<br>';
echo '30-39: '.$count_30_39.'<br>';
echo '40-49: '.$count_40_49.'<br>';  // example output is > 40-49: 7 (i.e. 7 patients in age group 40-49)
echo '50-59: '.$count_50_59.'<br>';
echo '60+: '.$count_above_60.'<br>';

// getting highest value

$a = array($count_0_19, $count_20_29, $count_30_39, $count_40_49, $count_50_59, $count_above_60);

$res = 0;
    foreach($a as $v) {
        if($res < $v)
            $res = $v;
    }

echo $res;
```

^^ This tells me that e.g. 9 patients are in the 30-39 age group - i.e. the highest number of patients are in this age group.

But $res gives me only the number (e.g. 9).

What I am asking your help with is to get $res to give me the text(or label) "30-39", instead of the number 9.

Please help.

Comment: make associative array like : `$a = array('0-19'=>$count_0_19, '20-29'=>$count_20_29, '30-39'=>$count_30_39,...);` and in `foreach`, get key also.

Comment: Do you mean like this?  foreach($a as $key => $v) {

Comment: Yes you have to use foreach($a as $key => $v)

Comment: @Bhaskar I have added the key like you said, but I still only get the number, not the label.                                                                     ' $a = array('0-19'=>$count_0_19, '20-29'=>$count_20_29, '30-39'=>$count_30_39, '40-49'=>$count_40_49, '50-59'=>$count_50_59, '60+'=>$count_above_60);
  $res = 0;
    foreach($a as $key => $v) {
 if($res < $v)
 $res = $v;
 }
          
 echo $res; '

Comment: @jamie, please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

continue from comment... you need to store `$key` into a variable.

```
$a = array('0-19'=>$count_0_19, '20-29'=>$count_20_29, '30-39'=>$count_30_39, '40-49'=>$count_40_49, '50-59'=>$count_50_59, '60+'=>$count_above_60); 
$res = 0; 
$label = '';
foreach($a as $key => $v) { 
    if($res < $v){
        $res = $v;
        $label = $key; //get label from key and store in a variable
    }
} 
echo 'label = '.$label . ' , Number = '.$res;
```

Comment: Solved. My apologies for not trying harder. I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can archived this by creating the array of labels and then incrementing it according and then find the greatest value form the `$label` array to get the key.

```
$label = [
  "0_19" => 0,
  "20_29" => 0,
  "30_39" => 0,
  "40_49" => 0,
  "50_59" => 0,
  "above_60" => 0,
];

while ($row4 = $result4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $pt_dob = explode('-', $row4['pt_dob']);
  $year = $pt_dob[0];
  $month = $pt_dob[1];
  $day = $pt_dob$temp = abs($curr_year - $year);
  if ($temp >= 0 && $temp <= 19) {
    $label['0_19'] = $label['0_19'] +1;
  }
  elseif ($temp >= 20 && $temp <= 29) {
    $label['20_29'] = $label['20_29'] +1;
  }
  elseif ($temp >= 30 && $temp <= 39) {
    $label['30_39'] = $label['30_39']+1;
  }
  elseif ($temp >= 40 && $temp <= 49) {
    $label['40_49'] = $label['40_49'] +1;
  }
  elseif ($temp >= 50 && $temp <= 59) {
    $label['50_59'] = $label['50_59']+1;
  }
  else {
    $label['above_60']= $label['above_60']+1;
  }
}


echo $maxs = array_keys($label, max($label));

echo "<br/>";


foreach($label as $k => $v);
    echo "key $k count $v <br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I get this at the end: ` Notice: Array to string conversion in..... ` and then: 'Array
0_19 = $0_19
20_29 = $20_29
30_39 = $30_39
50_59 = $50_59
60-100 = $60-100 `

Comment: Thanks again. Same notice error but then `Array
key above_60 count 0' - copied your code exactly but changed a (typo?) at line >>>  '$day = $pt_dob$temp = abs($curr_year - $year);' which should be >> $day = $pt_dob; $temp = abs($curr_year - $year); - Correct?